# How to enter data into Salesforce lightining?

Tags: lightning-apps, sandbox, data

I am trying to do the simplest thing in Salesforce Lightning. If I have a custom object called "Volunteer" that shows up on the Schema Builder, how do I manually enter some data records into the object ? I am not interested using the data loader at this time.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Tab (like "Volunteer") choosing that custom object.

And finally add the tab into App.

Note: User should have permission to tab and app in his profile. If you are a system admin, you will have permissions.

In that way, you can create records reaching the tab.